# Directus CMS: How to display cardinality count like in the admin using api endpoint

Tags: content-management-system, cardinality, directus

In the admin page of your Directus CMS you can see, when using a M2M and related O2M relation the number of records in the relation. I would like to display, using vuejs, that cardinality next to the category field and hide the categories with no relation yet.

Any idea on this ?

[image: Directus CMS collection with o2m relation]

Answer (score 0):

Well,
It looks as it goes like this

```
https://api........./items/blog_categories?meta=total_count&result_count&fields=*.*
```

So nothing more...and the meta can be omitted as it won't matter in the context of my question.